# Locking access to an object to edit it

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking, monitor

Lets say I have a single instance of an Image object that is going to be read and written to by two or more threads.

Would the following be the correct way to synchronise access?

I know that a cleaner way would be to use lock() { }, but then I would need a lockobject that all threads have access to? and I believe it would be bad practise to lock on the image object itself as other code could be doing that for an entirely different reason and cause a deadlock?

```
 public class Image
{
    public void Lock()
    {
        m_gotLock = false;
        Monitor.Enter(m_lock, ref m_gotLock);
    }

    public void Write()
    {
        // ...
    }

    public void Unlock()
    {
        if (m_gotLock)
        {
            Monitor.Exit(m_lock);
        }
    }

    object m_lock = new object();
    bool m_gotLock = false;
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Image image = new Image();

        new Thread(Work).Start(image);
        new Thread(Work).Start(image);
        new Thread(Work).Start(image);
    }

    static void Work(object param)
    {
        var img = (Image)param;
        while(true)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(100);

            img.Lock();
            img.Write();
            img.Unlock();
        }
    }
}
```

Edit : What about this approach?

```
public class Image
{
    public object Lock { get; } = new object();

    public void Write()
    {
        // ...
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Image image = new Image();

        new Thread(Work).Start(image);
        new Thread(Work).Start(image);
        new Thread(Work).Start(image);
    }

    static void Work(object param)
    {
        var img = (Image)param;
        while(true)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(100);

            lock(img.Lock)
            {
                img.Write();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Would it be possible and have you considered using immutable copies of the image?

Comment: Do not write your own lock/unlock code. Use the existing lock statement, because it is reliable.

Comment: Consider putting the locking **inside** the `Read` and `Write` methods - so the object is in charge of locking itself.

Comment: @mjwills What if I wanted to iterate over the content of the image without making a copy?

Comment: a) I'd suggest not doing that. b) If you really want to do that, move that logic **inside** the `Image` class (so it can control its own locking).

Comment: How would that itteration react to some other thread changing data it has not yet read? | Often you need to lock on multiple levels. The object itself can only do so much. The calling code has to do it's part.

Comment: @Christopher that would be the point of the locks? so only one thread can read or write to the image at a time

Comment: @mjwills not sure what you mean by moving it inside the image class? are you able to give an example?

Comment: Whatever logic that is interacting with the image - put it inside the `Image` class. Literally, inside that class. I can't really give any more specific guidance than that since your code sample doesn't show me what that logic is right now. In effect, the simplest way to make multiple threads work is this - a) Have the class itself do as much as possible, and manage its own locking b) Whenever the class exposes anything (such that it loses control of its own locking) do it in a thread-safe way (which usually means 'copy the thing' somehow).

Comment: `What about this approach?` Can you explain what is the benefit of doing it that way, rather than letting `Write` do the `lock` itself?

Comment: @mjwills in the case of Write() then I guess it provides no benefit. But in the case of iterating over the contents of the image without making a copy, isn't it quite safe? other than the case you mentioned below of people using the Lock property in a Monitor.Enter() and not calling Monitor.Exit(), but I am going to assume that would be a very rare thing.

Comment: @Cheesegrater :) clearly your code is rare as it does demonstrate problem of not calling `Exit` in case of an exception.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov do you mean if an exception is thrown in the first example? .. but that can't happen in the edited example though, right?

Comment: @Cheesegrater Indeed one with `lock { … }` does not have that problem - you could have fixed original with try/finally... But I'm still confused what you trying to achieve so - both approaches have exactly the same problem - class can't control correctness of pairing of locking calls (and you still have to add extra code to *every* method to validate proper locks are taken on current thread anyway)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov basically, all the APIs I have used to edit an Image (raw pixel data) have always had a pair of Lock/Unlock methods to write new pixel data, so I guess I was just trying to replicate what I have seen.

Comment: `But in the case of iterating over the contents of the image without making a copy, isn't it quite safe?` Again, I'd suggest you move that iterating **into the class**.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not a correct way to lock as it does not unlock object in case of an exception (as shown in the code in the post) or in general allows mismatching lock/unlock pairs.

```
     img.Lock();
     img.Write(); // exception causes object to never unlock
     img.Unlock();
```

Possible solutions for this particular issue:

- require `try`/`finally` for every place you use `Lock` to unlock inside `finally`.
- You can also expose `m_lock` as read-only property and let callers just use `lock {...}` statement. There is no particular benefits of hiding the object if you have to expose pair of methods as alternative as both approaches allow to end up with mismatched locking pair (also with object it requires explicit effort). And there is obvious drawback of two methods as there is no syntactic sugar to write correct code

  ```
  public object TheLock { get { return m_lock; } }
  ```
- move locking inside each method that accesses shared data so callers can't get it wrong for single method call.

  ```
  public void Write()
  {
      lock(m_lock)
      {
      // …
      }
  }
  ```
- have method that runs whatever code you want inside a lock <sup>1 :</sup>

  ```
  class Image { ...
    public T SafeOperation<T>(Func<Image, T> operation)
    {
        Lock();
        try 
        {
            return operation(this);
        }
        finally
        {
             Unlock();
        }
    }
  …}

  img.SafeOperation(x => x.Write());
  ```

Note that generally you need to have locking at higher level than individual objects to avoid spending all execution time on locking and releasing locks. Switching to immutable data structures as hinted by  mjwills in comments may simplify code...

<sub>1 As Christopher pointed out using `lock` statement would be simpler even for code inside the class and custom `Lock`/`Unlock` methods has no particular benefits there (as exactly the same code generated for `lock { … }`. Exposing lock object outside of the class (to use `lock` outside) has the same problems of misuse that object as `Lock`/`Unlock` pair that allows to lock incorrectly.</sub>

Comment: just use the lock statement. It is a try...finally, the same way using is. Als you code omitted the lock object.

Comment: @Christopher as I said in my original question, using the lock() would require all the threads to have access to the same locking object to pass into the lock()

Comment: @Christopher I've edited the answer that hopefully addressed you point.

Comment: @Cheesegrater That argument makes no sense. Do you honestly believe lock is doing something **other** then calling Monitor.Enter and Monitor.Exit in the finally block of a try...finally? Because that is exactly what it does: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/lock-statement All you are really doing is making your code more prone to fail and verbose by going your own way.

Comment: @Christopher I think you are missing my point. To use the c# lock(), I have to pass something into it to lock against. And all threads would have to have the same object being passed into lock(). So in my orginal question, if I was to replace the custom Lock/Unlock with the c# lock(x), what would you have me pass in as x?

Comment: @Cheesegrater to some extent it does not matter if you expose the locking object directly (obviously via get-only property so one can't change it from outside) or use your custom `Lock`/`Unlock` pair or even lock the object itself the problem of mismatched pairs is the same - there is nothing (expect code reviews) that prevents people to incorrectly lock either without matching unlock or for too long time...

Comment: …indeed always using `lock {…}` would be partial solution to it (as normal usage would not ever lead to mismatches) and easier to write than `try`/`finally` - but problem of potential misuse is still there.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov if locking using the built in lock(x) with an exposed lock object (get-only property), how would you get a missmatched pair?

Comment: @Cheesegrater because one can `Monitor.Enter(img.TheLock,...)` and miss/conditionally call `Leave` - especially when in mood to "optimize"...

Comment: @Cheesegrater The same is true for Monitor. Indeed you have to pass something in to fullfill **Monitors** need. And that you need to share this between all the threads in involved in this is: Well, Duh! You need a single shared resoruce to lock on, to get this kind of coordination. That is how the Mutex kind of Synchronisation works. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7ENFeb-J75k

Comment: @Christopher yes, but in none of your answers did you mention what that shared resource would be. So again - using the example in the original question, what would you use as the shared resource to pass into lock(x)?

Comment: @Cheesegrater ??? You already have the answer on what that mutex resoruce would be. You have it in that class code. A dedicated `object mutext = new object();` that all threads can access.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in order to lock you need a shared resource. That is how [lock/mutext pattern synchronsiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lock_(computer_science)) works.

You did the first part right, by having a dedicated mutex object (m_lock) to point Monitor at.

You seem to have a wierd, unexplainable issue with using the lock statement. You seem intent on calling Monitor.Enter() and .Exit(). This makes absolutely no sense, makes the code more verbose and orders more prone to error. Please just stop doing that.

```
function or property{
  lock(mutex){
    //do your Work here
  }
}
```

This is the minimum amount you can do for synchronsiation.

It is also the maximum you can do from inside that class.

**There are race conditions that no class code has any hope of preventing.** 
Only the calling code can prevent those.

That is likely *why* we do not have a [concurrent list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent?view=netframework-4.8) - Index Race conditions. The index becomming invalid, because someone added or removed something from it since getting that Index.

- Preventing Add() and Remove() Race Conditons? Not a problem. Use my above sample code.
- Preventing Index Race Condtions? Not a chance. Class code has the chance of a Snowball during the big bang to prevent that particular race condition.

Bag, Queue or Stack? Do not have a index to use, only add/remove or equivalents. Not a problem.
Dictionary? Uses a key. No race condition danger here. And yes, you can totally use `ConcurrentDictionary<int, T>` instead of List.

Array, List or anything else with a Index? Only the Calling code can prevent that forrest fire.

Comment: Side note: all types you've mentioned expose enumeration... with the same problem as indexing... but neither of those are new as "collection modified" problem is well known in single thread code already, also it's more debug-able in single thread case :)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Considering Enumerators become invalid once the underlying collection was changed, I do not really see an issue regarding Index RaceConditios here. Even if it internally itterates over a array of keys using a Index, it will just become invalid once the contents have been changed. | Actually not running into the Modification protection is another good case for "stuff only the calling code has any chance of doing".